# I need to split characters in R for every observation of a variable

Tags: r, split, statistics, character

I have a data frame and for one of the variables I need to split each of the observations by “,”

I used:

y <- strsplit(as.character(x), “,”)

I get a data set that shows every split character in a row not in the same row they were in before

I have this: “a,b,c,d…”
And need this: “a” “b” “c”…
For each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strsplit` returns a `list` of `vector`s.  If we have elements with different number of `,`, the `lengths` of the `list` will be different.  In that case, pad `NA` at the end (general case) based on the `max`imum `length`s of the `list` and then `rbind` to create a `matrix` in `base R`

```
# assuming the data.frame object name as 'df1', split the column x
# by `,` followed by zero or more spaces `\\s*`)
lst1 <- with(df1, strpslit(as.character(x), ",\\s*"))
# find the max lengths of the list
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
# pad NA at the end for elements with lesser length `length<-`
# and rbind the list elements 
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

---

This can also be done with `tidyverse` after splitting into a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(y = strsplit(as.character(x), ",\\s*")) %>%
    unnest_wider(y, names_sep = "")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the support this really helped! I'm new to R and coding in general so this is making me hopeful I'll somehow get the work done :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `separate()` from `tidyr()` and `dplyr()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Create data
data <-  tibble(rep(c("a,b,c", "ab,c", "cb,a"),5)) %>% 
            set_names("var1")

data %>% 
    separate(var1, into = c("var2", "var3", "var4"),   #Names of new columns
             sep = ",",   #Specify to separate at comma
             fill = "right",   #Pad remaining side with NA
             remove = FALSE)  #Keep original variable
```